# MySQL Reading from stream failed

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, visual-studio-2010

I am facing the following error intermittently. It is solved by using 'skip name resolve' option in the mysql server settings.

However, as per many suggestions found on net, using 127.0.0.1 should have solved the issue. But this too didn't help can you suggest me a workaround or a SQL command through which I can check the 'skip name resolve' option.

```
Error 1: 0
Authentication to host '127.0.0.1' for user 'root' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Reading from the stream has failed.

Stack Trace:
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.AuthenticationFailed(Exception ex)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.ReadPacket()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.Authenticate(Boolean reset)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Authenticate(String authMethod, Boolean reset)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
```

Comment: Just to be thorough: Did you login into your mysql database from the command prompt already just to see if your username/password work ok and the database itself is healthy?

Comment: Yes it does, this particular error comes up randomly.

Comment: We also facing the same issue on production. Anyone which can help with this please?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common error that happens when you update to MySQL Server 8.+.
By default MySQL 8 uses caching_sha2_password which is an upgraded authentication plugin over the mysql_native_password.

A way to fix this is by either specifically setting the plugin for the user's password to caching_sha2_password

```
CREATE USER 'sha2user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'password'
```

Updating the MySQL Server to accept mysql_native_passwords.

```
[mysqld]
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
```