# Reading from stream failed - mysql_native_password error

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, .net, database

I have been facing the following error intermittently.

**Authentication to host '127.0.0.1' for user 'root' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Reading from the stream has failed.**

It shots up any time and I am at my wits end. I also posted a bug on MySQL bugs and solutions are not proving to be effective in any way.I hope you guys can help me out.

Here is the link to MySQL Bug for details: [Never seems to go away](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=76597)!

Some more detail: I have a client-server system but this bug occurs on the server system(where MySQL database is installed) when a local running app on the server system tries to run a query.

I had already opened a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29460779/mysql-reading-from-stream-failed) but since has been dead. Just a caveat I thought that skip-name-resolve solved the issue but it seems to just have lowered the frequency. Hope someone would help me out this time around.

**EDIT**: The MySQL guys say that in a client server setup server may close a connection if it is unused for a long time. However, this is not what I am facing as I create a new connection everytime I want to execute a query. I made this point clear in the last comment on the MySQL Bugs.

Comment: What is the problem with the suggestions from MySQL forum?

Comment: Well what they are suggesting is for a connection which is open for a long time and now is invalid. When a app tries to access this invalid connection it gives an error. However, my case is different. I am opening a new connection for executing queries so that suggestion doesn't stand. Moreover, they are pointing that server can close a connection with client however, I am facing an error even if server talks to server(localhost query)

Comment: Okay, the thing that is confusing to me (and appears to be confusing others) is that you are saying that you have a "client-server system" and then go on to say that you get this error, "when a local running app on the server system tries to run a query".  To clarify, is the "local running app" the same client application that is running on other computers without errors?  (Or is the local app completely unrelated to the client-server application running on other [non-server] computers?)

Comment: If the local app is the same, then you may have some work-around possibilities until an actual fix can be found.  Trap the specific error when trying to open a connection and when you get it, log the error and retry opening the connection.  Since the issue is intermittent, it is likely to open the second time around.  (or third, etc.)  After maintaining a log for a period of time, you will hopefully be able to see a pattern form.  Regardless, the retry *should* mask the error from the users, thus working-around the problem in the short-term.

Comment: Just make things more clear. I would say forget Client server system. It is just a local app trying to access a local database where I get the error. Btw @DeadZone It is a good suggestion that I mask the error and try executing 2-3 times. But that would mean I would have to restructure a lot.

Comment: You should be able to wrap your OpenConnection call in a try/catch block.  Wrap that in a While loop that iterates while some `RetryFlag` variable is true where the catch block sets it to true.  If you want to prevent a possible infinite loop, change the `RetryFlag` to a `RetryCounter` and loop while the counter is < some value.  Logging the error would take more effort, but should be helpful in finding the root cause of the error.

Comment: I have already set a Tracelistener for this. Would be logging every error I get. But still it is really difficult to pin point this and running a for loop with a break is really inefficient I think. There must be another way.

Answer (score 15):

Guys I tried this: "SslMode=None" in the connection string, but if you need SSL then read this: 
http://www.voidcn.com/article/p-phfoefri-bpr.html

here is a sample connection string that works:

```
connectionString="Server=192.168.10.5;Database=mydata;Uid=root;Pwd=****;SslMode=None"
```

Hope this helps

Comment: SslMode=None : works fine for me, thanks

Comment: random behaviour still persist

Answer (score 5):

This issue is caused by Ssl.

Solution 1: SSL is not required. Since it is caused by SSL, we can turn off SSL by appending "SslMode=None" to the connection string.

Solution 2: SSL is required, server identity is important and needs to be verified. The server needs a internet connection to do the cert verification. Please note the crypto API doesn't update CTL for every process. The CTL is maintained at operating system level. Once you connect the server to connect and make an SSL database connection to the server, the CTL will be updated automatically. Then you may disconnect the internet connection. Note again the CTL has its expiration date and after that the Windows needs to update it again. This will occur probably after several months.

Solution 3: SSL is required but the server identity is not important. Typically SSL is only used to encrypt the network transport in this case. We can turn off CTL update:

Press Win+R to open the "Run" dialog
Type "gpedit.msc" (without quotes) and press Enter
In the "Local Group Policy Editor", expand "Computer Configuration", expand "Administrative Templates", expand "System", expand "Internet Communication Management", and then click "Internet Communication settings".
In the details panel, double-click "Turn off Automatic Root Certificates Update", clickEnabled, then click OK. This change will be effective immediatelly without restart.

http://www.voidcn.com/article/p-phfoefri-bpr.html

Answer (score 4):

I've been getting this error, quite frequently with Amazon's MySQL RDS instances. And most multi-AZ instances.

- It would be interesting to compare notes to see if others mostly get this issue with RDS also?

Amazon is known to rely heavily on "fast" DNS changes to switch over stuff with things like ELBs. I wonder if the same thing is happening with RDS? Or some other internal AWS switching is messing up the idle connections in the pool.

This would explain why the Oracle devs can't reproduce it and don't see it as much of an issue.

Anyway I've had to just deal with it and add retry logic when opening a connection.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue on AWS RDS. What does your retry logic look like?

Comment: I have the same problem with aws mysql database, this error is random

Answer (score 3):

unfortunately, this error occurs if the application and mysql are on the same computer, if you move it to a different computer it is fine.

I tried many ways but for now there is no other solution. bug has been reported many times by others https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=76597

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem performing the upgrade on a windows form application. The solution I found was to change the server, because that one was in trouble. On the server that was presenting the similar situation you described had installed WordPress with MYSQL 5.6.34, on the other I did a clean install with MYSQL version 5.6.26.

I don't know if it has to do with the environment variables used. I believe it has nothing to do with Connection Timeout, if it is a property that is used only with the open connection. This error occurred in a shared environment as well as in a local installation with Maria DB. Another problem I found was that one of the selection commands that retrieved the data was having a problem in its formation not respecting the blanks:

```
SELECT COLUNA1, COLUNA2 FROM TABLE;
```

I made the change to SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2 FROM TABLE;

I am still testing on this solution I presented, and as of the time of posting there were no more errors.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the error

> Authentication to host 'localhost' for user 'root' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Reading from the stream

I solved it when I put `SslMode=None` in my connection string.

However, I checked that the message is different from you

Check my connection

```
connection.ConnectionString = "server=myadressserver;userid=myuser;password=mypassword;database=test;SslMode=None";
```

Answer (score 0):

It is really weird, at the end i finally used an old version of MySql.Data.dll, 6.3.5.0 version worked in my C# app

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34681831)