# Calling a MySQL Routine in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, class

Please accept my apologies if I'm getting my verbiage wrong; I'm just now learning C# (my background is mostly Visual Basic and PHP).

What I'm trying to do is create a class / routine in C# (Windows Forms) for connecting and disconnecting to a MySQL database that can then be reused throughout the rest of my project without having to reiterate the code every time.

I've got my class / routine setup, but I'm stuck on trying to call it from the rest of my project. I know in Visual Basic this was a fairly simple task to do, but I just can't seem to figure it out how to do it in C#.

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

```
public void dbDisconnect(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     try
     {
          MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.mysql_db_conn_string);
          connection.Close();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
          MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method I currently have in my app:

```
public static MySqlConnection CreateConnection(
        string mysqlServer,
        string mysqlUser,
        string mysqlPassword,
        string mysqlDatabase)
{
    MySqlConnection mysqlConnection = null;

    string mysqlConnectionString = String.Format(
        "server={0};uid={1};pwd={2};database={3};DefaultCommandTimeout={4};",
        mysqlServer, mysqlUser, mysqlPassword, mysqlDatabase, 120);

    /** 
     ** Workaround for MySQL 5.6 bug:
     ** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30197699/reading-from-stream-failed-mysql-native-password-error 
     */
    int tryCounter = 0;
    bool isConnected = false;
    do
    {
        tryCounter++;
        try
        {
            mysqlConnection = new MySqlConnection();
            mysqlConnection.ConnectionString = mysqlConnectionString;
            mysqlConnection.Open();

            if (mysqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                isConnected = true;
            }
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            if (tryCounter < 10)
            {
                DebugLog.Dump(ex.ToString(), DebugLog.MainLogFilePath);
                Thread.Sleep(10000); // 10 seconds.
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    } while (!isConnected);

    return mysqlConnection;
}
```

Usage:

```
using (MySqlConnection hostsDbConnection = HostsDbConnector.CreateConnection())
{
    // Do something...
}
```

With `using` keyword you don't need to close the connection manually, it'll be closed automatically when it's no longer needed.